# .Net can Crystal Reports 13 use app pool identity to login to SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, webforms, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report embedded in a webform but it's unable to connect to SQL Server using app pool identity. We have a sql server using service account for web application access. I've configured the app pool id with service account credential. My web app is able to connect to SQL Server. 
Crystal report 13 and SQL SERVER 2016
web.config

```
<add name="ConnName" connectionString="server=ServerName; database=DB_Name; Trusted_Connection=yes;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

and Changed Crystal Report db setting

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder conString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnName"].ToString());
foreach (CrystalDecisions.Shared.IConnectionInfo RC in CReport.DataSourceConnections)
{
    RC.SetConnection(connectionInfo.ServerName, connectionInfo.DatabaseName, true);
    foreach (ReportDocument subReport in CReport.Subreports)
    {
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.Shared.IConnectionInfo subConn in subReport.DataSourceConnections)
        {
        rptConn.SetConnection(connectionInfo.ServerName, connectionInfo.DatabaseName, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Even though i changed the report connection it still prompt for db login.
how do i dynamically set the crystal report login for sql server using service account credential? or if i use trusted connection how do i impersonate the app pool identity.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample code taken from [Click to go to site](http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/files/print/csharp-crystal-reports-dynamic-login_print.htm).
It's sample code but a good starting point.  Compare with what you have currently and see if there is any difference.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
            TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
            TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
            ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
            Tables CrTables ;

            cryRpt.Load("PUT CRYSTAL REPORT PATH HERE\CrystalReport1.rpt");

            crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "YOUR SERVER NAME";
            crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "YOUR DATABASE NAME";
            crConnectionInfo.UserID = "YOUR DATABASE USERNAME";
            crConnectionInfo.Password = "YOUR DATABASE PASSWORD";

            CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables ;
            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
            {
                crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
                crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
            }

            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh(); 
        }
    }

}
```